# How to run VSCode on Centos6

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, centos6

My company is using an old CentOS6 and they wont update it before months (years?). This is totally out of my control and it obviously makes using up to date software a nightmare.

I would like to use Visual Studio Code as a C++ IDE but its intellisense plugin is running with glibc >=2.14 and Centos6 comes with glibc 2.12.

It also needed some more dependencies I managed to recompile and load with LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I tried compiling a new glibc and load it as well but it segfault, as expected.

I used the compiled version of VSCode from the official website.

I tried compiling it myself but it requires to download many files and my virtual machine does not have Internet, I can only transfer files through ftp. I created a local yarn repository, compiled all appropriate version of Yarn, NodeJS but a compiled binary is trying to download electron and I have no idea where to put the file to trick him into thinking it's downloaded already (assuming I could).

There are standalone solutions to run software on old distribution, like [AppImage](https://appimage.org/) but VSCode is not part of their apps.

Would you have any idea on how to run VSCode on Centos6? Did you ever try to compile VSCode without and Internet Connection?

Currently the only viable solution I see would be to create an AppImage at home.

Comment: this might be a long shot, but VScode is built with Electron so maybe these or similar steps could be taken for it to run on centos 6: http://endorkins.com/2017/04/26/running-nightmarejs-on-centos-6/

Answer (score 0):

To run VS Code Server on CentOS 6, I followed the "glibc and libstdc ++ on RHEL / CentOS 6 update" article from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/linux#_updating-glibc-and-libstdc-on-rhel-centos-6).
Perhaps this option will help you.